# Getting wiki summary in freebase

Tags: freebase

Here is a tv show query. How do I get the request to pull in the wiki summary?

```
[{
  "id" : "/m/0d68qy",
  "name": null
}]​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic summary is linked to a topic via the /common/topic/article property. You can retrieve this data in one API call using the new [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d68qy?filter=/common/topic/article